# C# is there a way to make my while loops start over?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make the while loops to start over when I order them to?
 something like if key != keyword then run the program again? 
I want to make both of the while loops work but it's impossible without using break; to stop one and start the other.

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
  string keyword = "End my suffering";
  string key = "";

  Console.Clear();

  while(keyword.ToLower() != key.ToLower())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to identity theft 2020\n");
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
    key = Console.ReadLine();
    break;
  } 

  while(keyword.ToLower() != key.ToLower())
  {
    Console.Write("\nNow your age please: ");
    key = Console.ReadLine();
    break;
  }

  Console.Clear();

  if(keyword.ToLower() == key.ToLower()){
    Console.WriteLine("Sad :c");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("\nSee you next time. I guess?");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can execute them async. Then you should execute both.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Are you sure you want to use `while` loops like that?

Comment: Yes it does execute both, but if I try to store for example a name value or a age value it wont work

Comment: I'm trying to make a program go on forever if a certain keyword isn't typed in.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a `nested-while loop`.

Comment: It looks like you want just one `while` loop containing all the prompts/inputs, and then it loops and retests the condition to see if it should run those prompts again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could make a nested while loop...  that's exactly what I needed thanks!